# Parsing date with the contents of a previous date execution issues error

Tags: command-line, date

I'm facing some trouble with the date command. The following execution issues an error:

```
danilo@desktop:~$ x=$(date -d "+60 seconds"); dt=$(date -d "$x")
date: invalid date ‘Mo 11. Sep 09:07:05 CEST 2017’
```

This is strange, because it works in other computers I tested. Even this:

```
danilo@desktop:~$ x=$(date); dt=$(date -d "$x")
date: invalid date ‘Mo 11. Sep 09:06:43 CEST 2017’
```

Produces an error.

What is the reason for this error? Is it the timezone settings? How can I make it work?

Comment: It was empty before. It's being created with the results of the date command on the first part of the command.

Comment: Another way to express this is simply: $ date -d "$(date)". It's giving an error on the computer I'm testing, but it works in another that I have access via ssh and tested now.

Comment: there is no question in this post

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default format for your locale is not supported as input to date.  The solution is to use some standard format.  For example:

```
x=$(date -d "+60 seconds" +%s); dt=$(date -d "@$x")
```

`+%s` tells `date` to return a standard Unix format: seconds-since-epoch.

The `@` sign in `date -d "@$x"` tells `date` to interpret `$x` as seconds-since-epoch.

Comment: I understand now. This works fine, thank you. Do you know how to fix the  locale?

Comment: @DaniloM.Oliveira You can change the locale by changing the shell variable `LC_TIME`.  For example, `export LC_TIME=C` will tell date to use the common C locale (and will make sure the variable is exported so that subshells see it as well.